# Showing progress view when communicating with web-service

Tags: web-services, ios, uiprogressview

in my application start, i'm requesting data and parsing by communicating with web-service via JSON, this work takes sometime 2 seconds, so i want to show the user a UIProgressView when this work is being executed and when it's done, i will redirect the user to the main view of my application, can you please help me there ? what objects to use essentially and if you have tutorials tips, i wil be glad, thx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).  You're going to want to use the `setDownloadProgressDelegate:` method to hook it up to your progress indicator.  Something like this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:someProgressIndicator];
[request startSynchronous];
```

For further reading see the relevant portion of the documentation here:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_progress

Comment: thx, and i will keep you informed if i encounter any problem with that :)